# Can I create a cell with enumerated values in a csv file

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, csv

Can I create a cell with enumerated values in a **csv** file?

For example, I want a cell that can only get the values:

a) "value1"

b) "value2"

c) "value3"

Is this possible?

---

PS:

I have used this method:

```
data->dataValitation->list->select Desirable Area.
```

But when I try to save it and reopen it the enumeration is not there. Before the saving part, the enumerating list works ok.

PS2: I am using MS Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your title is `Can I create a cell with enumerated values in a csv file`. Therefore, I will assume you're editing with Excel but saving to CSV.

You can't do this with CSV. CSV is just a file type (comma separated values).

The reason you get the functionality is because you're using Excel to read the CSV. If you want that to persist that, you need to save it as an .XLSX file (an Excel file) because when you save it to a CSV file, that extra functionality/data is not saved.

Comment: You are right, maybe i should mention that i was using MS Excel... Unfortunately, i want csv so, as you said, the answer is 
"NO". Thanks anyway for answering.